# How to access service provider in ASP.NET Core Lambda function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aws-lambda

I have a C# Lambda function that inherits from `APIGatewayProxyFunction`.

```
public class LambdaFunction : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public LambdaFunction(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        : base()
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = accessor;
    }

    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseLambdaServer();
    }
}
```

As this is an ASP.NET Core project, I'm configuring the application dependencies in the `Startup.cs` class like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

However, since the `LambdaFunction` class is the actual Lambda entry point that is called when the Lambda runs, it seems like the `IHttpContextAccessor` object passed to its constructor wouldn't be resolved since `ConfigureServices` hasn't run before `LambdaFunction` is instantiated.

Is this understanding correct? I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the request path correctly. If so, what would be the best way to access the `IHttpContextAccessor` object (or more generally, the `IServiceProvider` built by the `Startup` class) inside the `LambdaFunction.FunctionHandlerAsync()` function body?